# submit a form using external js

Tags: javascript

How to submit a form using external js ? using form name or id is not working,
Showing this error 
TypeError: document.forms.adminForm.submit is not a function

> document.forms["adminForm"].submit();

adminForm is name & id of the form

Comment: `console.log(document.forms, document.forms["adminForm"]);` - check if you have found the form correctly

Comment: its showing [form index.php, form index.php, form#adminForm index.php]

<form id="adminForm" onsubmit="return validate('answer')" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" method="post" action="index.php">

Comment: Is this all the script that is involved? Can you post the actual script?

Comment: zerkms told to check the form with console.log.....the result is  "[form index.php,........."....My code is document.forms["adminForm"].submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: document.forms.adminForm.submit is not a function

means that you named your submit button or some other element  as 'submit'. Rename the button to something else and your code will work.

Comment: Hi Rab Nawaz,Thank you very much....now its working...i removed the input element name "Submit".....